# Rails: Why is this form triggering the wrong action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, controller, heroku

I have a form in my app which is triggering the wrong controller action. Here's the rendered form:

```
<form id="edit_profile_1" class="simple_form profile windowed" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profiles/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
  <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
  <input type="hidden" value="put" name="_method">
  <input type="hidden" value="..." name="authenticity_token">
  </div>
....
</form>
```

So, pretty much a normal form. On my local environment this works fine, it triggers the `profiles#update` action. However, when deployed on Heroku for some reason this is triggering the `profiles#show` action, and therefore is not working.

What gives? Has anyone encountered this error before, and do you know how to fix it?

-EDIT- @Laas: Here's the production log:

```
2011-05-20T21:41:38+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/account" for 98.201.59.6 at 2011-05-20 14:41:38 -0700
2011-05-20T21:41:40+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.fourthenvironment.org/account dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2212ms bytes=8672
2011-05-20T21:41:40+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to NewRelic Service at collector-6.newrelic.com:80
2011-05-20T21:41:40+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.fourthenvironment.org/javascripts/rails.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms bytes=5176
2011-05-20T21:41:41+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.fourthenvironment.org/javascripts/jquery.144.min.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms bytes=78865
2011-05-20T21:41:42+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.fourthenvironment.org/stylesheets/style.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms bytes=63444
2011-05-20T21:41:47+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.fourthenvironment.org/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms bytes=1672
2011-05-20T21:41:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-05-20T21:41:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-05-20T21:41:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/profiles/1" for 98.201.59.6 at 2011-05-20 14:41:50 -0700
2011-05-20T21:41:50+00:00 heroku[router]: POST www.fourthenvironment.org/profiles/1 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=102ms bytes=420
2011-05-20T21:41:50+00:00 app[web.1]: THIS SHOULD NOT BE TRIGGERED
2011-05-20T21:41:50+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.fourthenvironment.org/profiles/1 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=30ms bytes=414
2011-05-20T21:41:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-05-20T21:41:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-05-20T21:41:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/account" for 98.201.59.6 at 2011-05-20 14:41:50 -0700
```

Note the "THIS SHOULD NOT BE TRIGGERED". Here's the controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def show
        puts "THIS SHOULD NOT BE TRIGGERED"
        redirect_to account_path
    end


    def edit
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        puts "profiles#update"
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
        if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
            redirect_to account_path, :notice => t('user.notice.updated')
        else
            render :action => 'edit'
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Only two ways for this to happen: a) Browser actually `GET`s the action or b) Rails router somehow matches the show even on `POST`. Do you have access to production log? It indicates what method and params Rails actually understood from the request.

Comment: That's crazy, it's not your first post concerning differences between your local dev and your heroku deployment. By default, heroku uses ruby 1.8.7 enterprise edition, do you have it in local?

Comment: I'm running MRI 1.9.2 in both production and local.

Comment: @apneadiving FWIW I'm also running Thin and tested this on Thin Production, to get as close to the heroku dyno setup as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was related to the use of the SSL-Requirement Gem. For some reason if you send a request from an SSL page to a non-SSL page while using SSL-requirement it gets redirected. So, to fix, enable SSL-requirement on both ends of the request, and it will work. It looks like going from SSL to non SSL the gem only allows gets -- hence the bug. This looks to be irrelevant as of Rails 3.1 since a new SSL requirement functionality will be baked-in and the gem will not be required.

Many thanks to the Heroku staff for helping isolate this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be identical to this problem [routing-issues-with-multi-part-forms-on-heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000044/routing-issues-with-multi-part-forms-on-heroku).

As it is only few days old, maybe it is not a coincidence and there's something awry with Heroku?

Comment: One difference: my issue is on every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the form tag hard coded? Use the form_tag helper

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Comment: The form tag is not hard coded. I was showing the rendered output above to show what the URL the browser is actually working with is. I am using the form helper.